# Printing a variable numbers in the same line, to go to the nexline after these variable number

Tags: java, arrays, printing

I want to let the user to enter a column length. Lets say '4'. Then it should printout like this:

1  2  3  4

5  6  7  8

9 10 11 12

13 14 15 16

In a square of 4 by 4.

I don't expect my code to be anywhere near to the solution I am looking for. It's just a simple printout line. But this one needs some necessary modifying.

how can I manage this?

```java
package MagicMatrix;

import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Matrix
{

    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);   

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {

        new Matrix();

    }

    public Matrix() 

    {

        System.out.println("Give column length of matrix\n");

        int var00 = 1;
        int columnlength = scanner.nextInt();

        int [][] matrix = new int [columnlength][columnlength];


        for (int i=0; i < columnlength; i++) 
        {
            for (int j=0; j < columnlength; j++ )
            {
                matrix[i][j] = var00;
                var00++;
            }
        }

        for (int i=0; i < colomnlength; i++) 
        {
            for (int j=0; j < colomnlength; j++ )
            {

            System.out.print(matrix[i][j]); // The big question!!!!

            }
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Instead of dumping a ton of code, can you identify what exactly isn't working with your code?

Comment: @Frontear If you scroll down you'll see a line that is marked 'The big question!!!' that's where some adaptations needs to be done!

Comment: Please explain with your **error** statements or the problems arising to you in building the logic.

Comment: @Pulkit Jatav Currently the printoutline gives 12345678910111213141516 but I want it to be like
 1    2   3   4

 5    6   7   8

 9  10 11 12

13 14 15 16

In rows and columns of 4 by 4

Answer (score 2):

Contrary to what you said in your question, you were actually quite close to the solution. You only need to replace `var1` (which i have no idea where that came from) with your `var00` and right after the inner loop (the one iterating with `j`) add a `System.out.println()` to go to the next line after one row. That should theoretically work.

```
for (int i=0; i < columnlength; i++) 
    {
        for (int j=0; j < columnlength; j++ )
        {
            matrix[i][j] = var00;
            var00++;
        }
    }

for (int i=0; i < columnlength; i++)
    {
        for (int j=0; j < columnlength; j++ )
            {
                System.out.print(matrix[i][j] + " "); 
            }
        System.out.println();
    }
```

Edit: I noticed that you called it once `columnlength`and once `colomnlength` you should probably fix that. Also add a space after `matrix[i][j]` by doing `+ " "` so there's a bit of space between the numbers

Comment: OHHH Thanks man!! that was it. (about that var00 and var1 I changed that while editing my question but  forgot to change them all). But your suggestion was PERFECT!!

Comment: @Twannemannn Glad I could help, don't forget to mark it as the correct answer if it worked

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve this by using only two loops also.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Hello
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);   

    int columnlength = scanner.nextInt();

    int [][] matrix = new int [columnlength][columnlength];
    int counter = 1;

    for(int i = 0;i<columnlength;i++) {
        for(int j=0;j<columnlength;j++) {
            matrix[i][j] = counter;
            System.out.print(counter+++"\t");
        }
        System.out.println();
    }

}

}
```

Comment: Filling the matrix with the counter is probably not what he wants to do in the resulting program but just to have some example data. In any case, it is usually preferable to separate code of different functionality, like filling a matrix and printing it, even if that produces a little bit of boiler plate.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure I understand your question fully, perhaps this will solve your problem:

```
    for (int i=0; i < colomnlength; i++) 
    {
        System.out.print(matrix[i][0]);
        for (int j=1; j < colomnlength; j++ )
        {

            System.out.print(matrix[i][j]); // The big question!!!!

        }
        System.out.println();
    }
```